# Reading NSobject property from within NSArray

Tags: objective-c, properties, nsarray, nsobject

I created this Class to store Rss feeds about Cd-rooms:

CdObject.h

```
@interface CdObject : NSObject{


NSString *title,*artist,*country,*company,*price,*year;

}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *title,*artist,*country,*company,*price,*year;
```

CdObject.m

```
#import "CdObject.h"

@implementation CdObject
@synthesize title,artist,country,company,price,year;

@end
```

Then while parsing the xml i'm creating new instances of this class filling their properties (title,artist ect..)and pushing them into a NSMutableArray (cdListArray)

How could I read the property of one of these objects from inside cdListArray?

```
Ex:NSLog(@"%@",[cdListArray objectAtIndex:0].title) ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `NSLog(@"%@",((CdObject*)[cdListArray objectAtIndex:0]).title)`

Comment: I tried it says "property 'title' not found on object of type 'id'"..but i think i missed the parenthesis =)

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, the simples way in all such cases is `valueForKey:` and it's brother `valueForKeyPath:`

Comment: what's the difference between those two

Comment: valueForKey: reads a single property of the object, valueForKeyPath: can read a property of any sub-item and any deep. For instance, with the first one you can read [[cdListArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"title"] and with the second [[cdListArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKeyPath:@"item.subitem.subsubitem.title"].

Answer (score 1):

You simply cast it to the object you want.  If you're paranoid about type casting that way, you can also check the object's class before the cast.

Ex:

```
NSObject *firstObject = [cdListArray objectAtIndex:0];
if ( [firstObject isKindOfClass:[CdObject class]] )
{
    CdObject* cdFirstObject = (CdObject*)firstObject;
    NSLog(@"%@", cdFirstObject.title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to cast:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[(CdObject *)[cdListArray objectAtIndex:0]] title);
```